# Should I release @property (nonatomic, copy)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm using `UISearchBar`, and one of its properties,  `text`, is declared as follows:

**Abstract**: The current or starting search text.
**Declaration**: `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;`

I know that the rule is to release what ever you use `+alloc`, `+new` or `-copy`.

I did:

```
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
```

And:

```
[searchText release];
```

And I got a nice `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message. When I removed the release line, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message stopped to appear, so I assumed that it is the eror source.

The question: Shouldn't I release `searchText`, since it comes from a property that uses copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you should not use release here. The "copy" in this case refers to how the setter is implemented, not the getter. The call *you* made (`-text`) does not include the word "copy" so you should not release the result.

Comment: Well, but... If it's going to be gotten (`get`'ed?), it must have been set somewhere. I don't think this is really an answer to the question. The question really is: does the `copy` setter semantic retain the same way the `retain` one does, consistent with the `-copy` NSObject method, and the answer is that no it doesn't, what it's saying is, it makes a unique copy that it `assign`s.

Comment: @Dan Ray, it may or may not make a unique copy that is assigned. It may do a lot of things. It may retain if the target object is immutable. It might create a completely different type of object having little in common with the one passed (I do this a lot in C++ wrappers). "copy" is a hint to the caller and provides a default implementation if you let the setter be created by @synthesize. But the question was whether to call -release on the result of -searchText, and the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The copy attribute of the property means that the object is copied before *assigning* to the instance variable. When you access this property you then get a reference to the copy that was made.

When you set the the text on the searchbar:

```
NSString* myTextString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"My Text String"];
mySearchBar.text = myTextString;
[myTextString release];
```

Comment: Do **not** use `retainCount`.  The code is fine up to the last line.  If you were to actually run that code, the retain count would be -1 (depending on implementation details).

Comment: Removed the last line after reading Rob Napier's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cool -- thanks -- I'd suggest removing the comment, too.  Whether or not the object is destroyed after that -release is entirely an implementation detail of `mySearchBar` and not something the caller should consider.

Comment: Can't I assign NSString by: NSString *str = @"123"; ?

Comment: Yea of course! That's the best way to quickly get hold of a string. I justed used this method as an example. The string you get using the shorthand @"string" notation is an autoreleased string.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Rob Napier's correct answer:

```
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
```

This code assigns a reference to the text property of `searchBar` to `searchText`. This is not a copy of the `searchText`, just another reference to the same `NSString` object in the `searchBar` object.  Releasing `searchText` is the same as releasing `searchBar.text`, which cause your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message.

In this declaration of the text property, the getter method is merely:

```
- (NSString *)text {
   return text;
}
```

The more interesting method is the setter method. For this declaration, the setter is similar to:

```
- (Void)setText:(NSString *)newString {
  if (text != newString) {
    [text release];
    text = [newString copy];
  }
}
```